# ASP .NET RowUpdating GridView Troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble with the `RowUpdating` Method.  My `GridView` is connected to our local SQL Server, and I'm trying to update the data. Here is the code for the `RowUpdating` Method from MSDN.

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["TaskTable"];

        //Update the values.
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Id"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Description"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["IsComplete"] = ((CheckBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked;

        //Reset the edit index.
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        BindData();

}
```

I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You're accessing so many items without null checks that it could be any number of things. Which line is throwing the exception? Are you sure all of the controls exist in the cells you're specifying? Are you sure the cells themselves exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code once.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    TextBox tname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("nam");
    TextBox tques = (TextBox)row.FindControl("que");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update exam set name1=@name,ques=@ques where id = @id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = tname.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ques", MySqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value = tques.Text.Trim();
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bind();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all GridViewRow have a DataItem.

You should add a `if` block around your code and verify the row being updated is of type `DataRow`.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
     your code here...
}
```

More regarding RowTypes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
public void bindGvEdit()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = obj1.SelectAlltbl();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindGvEdit();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bindGvEdit();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    obj1.Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
    obj1.Name = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[1]).Text;
    obj1.Description = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[1]).Text;
    obj1.Updatetbl();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bindGvEdit();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In your next posts, please make sure your code formatting is correct.