# Trying to fetch values on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to fetch values on a GridView with the following code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    string Username = row.Cells[3].Text;
    string Password = row.Cells[4].Text;
    string Email = row.Cells[5].Text;
    string ID_Inscricao = row.Cells[1].Text;
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FormacaoConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();

    sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.Text);
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.Text);
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.Text);
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ID_Inscricao", SqlDbType.Text);

    sqlComm.Parameters["@Username"].Value = Username;
    sqlComm.Parameters["@Password"].Value = Password;
    sqlComm.Parameters["@Email"].Value = Email;
    sqlComm.Parameters["@ID_Inscricao"].Value = ID_Inscricao;
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Utilizadores " +
        "(Username, Password, Email,ID_Inscricao) " +
        "VALUES (@Username, @Password, @Email, @ID_Inscricao)";
    sqlComm.CommandText = sql;
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConn.Close();
}
```

So, the problem is I can't get the values from the GridView, but instead get a "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code". Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards

Comment: Could you tell us on what line you're getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Scratch that, I think I see it - you're setting the values of parameters that you've not yet created (specifically, you've commented out the lines at actually set the parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line which looks like this:

```
sqlComm.Parameters["@Username"].Value = Username;
```

Requires that parameter to actually exist on the command object, but you've commented those lines out. Put back in one of these:

```
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.Text);
```

For every parameter you're setting the value for.

---

**Edited after comment**

Based on the fact that this line causes a `NullReferenceException`:

```
string Username = row.Cells[3].Text;
```

I can say for cetain that either

a) `row` is null - there is no SelectedRow in your grid
 b) `row.Cells` is null, the selected row has no cells
 c) `row.Cells[3]` is null, the selected row has cells, but there is no cell 4(cells is zero based)

There is no way of helping you further than that, You should set a breakpoint on the line that is failing and inspect each of the 3 cases above to see which one is null

Comment: sorry about that they arent, commented in the working version, the error occurs, "string Username = row.Cells[3].Text;"

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options, depending on how your bound the items.
You could do:
Row.Cells["NAMEOFBINDING"] and this will get you the value.
There are many hidden cells you might now see.

You might want to try a different event too, like "RowUpdated"
Also, try looking at your event args and see if it has any juicy information for you.

If you don't have an answer to your satisfaction in an hour, I'll write a code sample.

Comment: im doing in row updated because de line disapears after de update, because on of the values become true. And the table doesnt call them in the "Select"

Comment: This may be of some help to you. Similar question already asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437903/asp-net-rowupdating-gridview-troubles

Comment: Nice i solved the problem, but having problem converting label to bigint for DB