# Updating row cells throwing out of range exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, webforms

I'm trying to update a row in a gridview in a webform app, I'm getting a format exception. My other stored procedures are working and I've checked these against this code and cannot find where this one is failing. All else in the app is working.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

My stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProd 
    @pId int, @catId int, 
    @pname varchar(15), 
    @pdesc1 varchar(25), @pdesc2 varchar(50), 
    @pprice dec(8,2)
AS
    UPDATE Prod
    SET CatID = @catId,
        PName = @pname, 
        PDesc1 = @pdesc1, 
        PDesc2 = @pdesc2, 
        Price = @pprice
    WHERE ProdId = @pId;
GO
```

My data binding etc for updating.

```
public static void UpdateProduct(string[] param1)
{
    // SqlConnection.
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "UpdateProd";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = param1[0];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@catId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = param1[1];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = param1[2];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdesc1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = param1[3];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdesc2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = param1[4];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pprice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = param1[5];
    // etc .../
```

My method to update the row.

```
protected void GVProducts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GVProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string[] param = { row.Cells[1].Text.ToString(), row.Cells[2].Text.ToString(),
    row.Cells[3].Text.ToString(), row.Cells[4].Text.ToString(), row.Cells[5].Text.ToString(),
    row.Cells[6].Text.ToString() };
    Login.UpdateProduct(param);
}
```

My markup for the GridView columns

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProdID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                    SortExpression="ProdID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CatID" HeaderText="Cat" SortExpression="CatID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PName" HeaderText="Product Name" SortExpression="PName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PDesc1" HeaderText="Short Product Description" SortExpression="PDesc1" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PDesc2" HeaderText="Long Product Description" SortExpression="PDesc2" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
</Columns>
```

I'm getting a

> System.FormatException

I'm starting the index for the row cells at 1, which works when selecting on prodId for deleting. I assume the first column (index 0) is taken up by the [edit/select]. I have tested changing the indices in both directions and this has not helped.

[image]

---

**Edit**

The actual row is only showing up the Cells index = 1. The greater indices are throwing an out of range exception. So this is curious. Is there something I need to know when setting up the gridview, re Cells?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP .NET RowUpdating GridView Troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437903/asp-net-rowupdating-gridview-troubles)

Comment: In addition to not checking for NULL you also don't specify the length of the parameters. For both characters and your decimals you should be explicit in the data size.

Comment: The first thing I would do is to stop building and passing a string array. Instead I would pass each parameter. It is easier to code and easier to debug and eliminates a lot of ambiguity. You also can specify the datatypes, which is possibly the issue here. You are passing in strings and then hoping they can implicitly be cast to an int. Off topic but I would also recommend wrapping your connection in a USING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to stop building and passing a string array. Instead I would pass each parameter. It is easier to code and easier to debug and eliminates a lot of ambiguity. You also can specify the datatypes, which is possibly the issue here. You are passing in strings and then hoping they can implicitly be cast to an int. Off topic but I would also recommend wrapping your connection in a USING.